# How to trace all HTTP request invoked by Playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework, logback, typesafe-activator, securesocial

For example, I am using OAuth2 Authentication in Playframework by play-silhouette (or SecureSocial). I want to track the HTTP requests so that I could know how Playframework communicate with Facebook, which provides OAuth2 service.

Is there a way to print all HTTP request invoked by Playframework in log file？

Comment: Have you tried `logger.com.ning.http.client=DEBUG` in your `application.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe write this in `conf` file could solves this issue..

```
logger.play=TRACE
logger.application=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filters: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#a-simple-logging-filter

Filter intercept every request - you can return that request with no modifications, logging any details you're interested in.